# Swift - reading a file into a string array

Tags: arrays, swift, file-handling

Having trouble with reading a file inside the project folder into a `String` array.

Here is my code:

```
 func readfile() -> [String] {
print("Please enter the name of your file")
let path = String(readLine()!)!
var array: [String]?

do {
    // Read an entire text file into an NSString.
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: path, ofType: "txt"){
        let data = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        array = data.components(separatedBy: ",")
        print(array!)
    }
} catch let err as NSError {
    print("Unable to read the file at: \(path)")
    print(err)
}
return array! // I get a fatal error here, "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code.

Comment: beacuse array does not contain any data and you are force unwrapping the optional value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call a function and use its value before the function returns the value

```
let path = String(readLine()!)!
```

So you try force unwrap an optional value which at the moment is nil. Also you should use another way to turn a array into a string.

Comment: FYI - the error is not from the line in your answer. It's from the last line in answer's code.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry to interrupt. Actually the error is on that line. I ran his code and found that `let path = String(readLine()!)!` produces the error.

Comment: @nayem My comment is based on the code posted in the question. There is a comment in the code clearly stating the error is on the last line. Did you try the code in a macOS command line app or maybe under Linux? It may behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to read from the console. Is this project a *command line project*? Anyway, use this to investigate the issue:

```
func readfile() -> [String] {
    print("Please enter the name of your file")

    let filename = String(readLine()!)!
    var array: [String]?

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "txt") {
        do {
            let text = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            array = text.components(separatedBy: ",")
            // print(array)
            return array!
        } catch {
            print("Failed to read text from: \(filename)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Failed to load file from app bundle: \(filename)")
    }
    return [""]
}
```

Comment: I just made a test project using the macOS command line template. The code posted in this question fails on the last line (`return array!`) as long as you actually provide some text to the running app. The problem is not the call to `readLine()`.

Comment: @rmaddy well, now I get this. The problem is actually getting _full pathname for the resource_ from `Main Bundle`. It doesn't execute `if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: path, ofType: "txt")` and so `array` is **nil**

Comment: Clearly the issue is passing the correct value for the bundle. The OP has done a poor job of providing useful details or debugging before posting.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah. Isn't a command line project able to read from `Main Bundle` by the way??